# Drawing scalar field in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, field, scalar

Now I have a scalar field in three dimensional space which is

`v=-1*(1-(b./sqrt(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2)).^3).*z`  only for  `sqrt(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2)>b`;

otherwise `v=0`

Now i want to draw the scalar field by using "slice" function

My code:

```
[x,y,z]=meshgrid(-10:1:10);
b=1;
%v=-1*(1-(b./sqrt(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2)).^3).*z;
if ((x.^2+y.^2+z.^2)>=b)
    v=-1*(1-(b./sqrt(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2)).^3).*z;
else
    v=0
end
h=slice(x,y,z,v,[],[],-10:1:10);
set(h,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','interp')
alpha(.5)
```

But eventually i get these error:

> Error using griddedInterpolant The grid vectors do not define a grid
>   of points that match the given values.
>
> Error in interp3 (line 142)
>               F = griddedInterpolant(X, Y, Z, V,
>               method,extrap);
>
> Error in slice (line 100)
>       vi = interp3(x,y,z,v,xi,yi,zi,method);
>
> Error in Electromagnetism_graph2 (line 11)
>   h=slice(x,y,z,v,[],[],-10:1:10);

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you do, but this seems to work fine (no error). I think your error is in `if-else`. You are assigning a `0` (scalar) if the condition fails. You should make only that element of `v` equal to zero.

```
[x,y,z]=meshgrid(-10:1:10);
b=1;
v=-1*(1-(b./sqrt(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2)).^3).*z;
indMat=sqrt(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2)>b;
v(~indMat)=0;
h=slice(x,y,z,v,[],[],-10:1:10);
```